# How to run a BigQuery query in Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

This is the query that I have been running in BigQuery that I want to run in my python script. How would I change this/ what do I have to add for it to run in Python.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Serial,
  MAX(createdAt) AS Latest_Use,
  SUM(ConnectionTime/3600) as Total_Hours,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DeviceID) AS Devices_Connected
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.testf`
WHERE Model = "BlueBox-pH"
GROUP BY Serial
ORDER BY Serial
LIMIT 1000;
```

From what I have been researching it is saying that I cant save this query as a permanent table using Python. Is that true? and if it is true is it possible to still export a temporary table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the [BigQuery Python client lib](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery), then something like this should get you up and running:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')
query = "SELECT...."
dataset = client.dataset('dataset')
table = dataset.table(name='table')
job = client.run_async_query('my-job', query)
job.destination = table
job.write_disposition= 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job.begin()
```

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html

See the current [BigQuery Python client tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Comment: The https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html link returns 404 error

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I'll add this here.  You need to specify a job_config setting `use_legacy_sql` to `False` for the OP's query to run. The default is `True`.

e.g.
```python
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way using a JSON file for the service account:

```py
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>>
>>> CREDS = 'test_service_account.json'
>>> client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path=CREDS)
>>> job = client.query('select * from dataset1.mytable')
>>> for row in job.result():
...     print(row)
```

Comment: I think the final line should be `print(row)`

Answer (score 3):

This is a good usage guide:
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/index.html

To simply run and write a query:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# dataset_id = 'your_dataset_id'

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
# Set the destination table
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table("your_table_id")
job_config.destination = table_ref
sql = """
    SELECT corpus
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    GROUP BY corpus;
"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(
    sql,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query
    # and of the destination table.
    location="US",
    job_config=job_config,
)  # API request - starts the query

query_job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish
print("Query results loaded to table {}".format(table_ref.path))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Google Cloud BigQuery Python client library:

   pip install google-cloud-bigquery
2. Authenticate with Google Cloud:

**Code**:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
def check():
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file. All clients in google-cloud-python have this helper method.

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'path/to/key.json')
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)

    # OR
    # If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the client
    # library will look for credentials in the environment.

    # client = bigquery.Client()

    # Construct a reference to the "hacker_news" dataset

    dataset_ref = client.dataset("hacker_news", project="bigquery-public-data")

    # API request - fetch the dataset
    dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

    # Construct a reference to the "comments" table
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table("comments")

    # API request - fetch the table
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)

    # Run a SQL query on the table
    sql = """
        SELECT COUNT(*) as total_comments
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
    """

    query_job = client.query(sql)  # Make an API request

    # Print the results
    for row in query_job:
        print(row.total_comments)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer querying using pandas:

```
# BQ authentication
import pydata_google_auth
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]

credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    SCOPES,
    # Set auth_local_webserver to True to have a slightly more convienient
    # authorization flow. Note, this doesn't work if you're running from a
    # notebook on a remote sever, such as over SSH or with Google Colab.
    auth_local_webserver=True,
)

query = "SELECT * FROM my_table"

data = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id = MY_PROJECT_ID, credentials=credentials, dialect = 'standard')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [pythonbq](https://github.com/connor-makowski/pythonbq) package is very simple to use and a great place to start. It uses python-gbq.

To get started you would need to generate a BQ json key for external app access. You can generate your key [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey).

Your code would look something like:

```
from pythonbq import pythonbq

myProject=pythonbq(
  bq_key_path='path/to/bq/key.json',
  project_id='myGoogleProjectID'
)
SQL_CODE="""
SELECT
  Serial,
  MAX(createdAt) AS Latest_Use,
  SUM(ConnectionTime/3600) as Total_Hours,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DeviceID) AS Devices_Connected
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.testf`
WHERE Model = "BlueBox-pH"
GROUP BY Serial
ORDER BY Serial
LIMIT 1000;
"""
output=myProject.query(sql=SQL_CODE)
```